# Скорость запроса в БД в laravel увеличивается при повторе запроса. Как это работает?

Tags: sql, laravel

Давайте первоначально договоримся, что я возможно делаю всё не так и у вас глаза на лоб полезли от вопроса. Ничего страшного, потерпите (=

Хочу протестировать разные запросы к бд и сравнить скорость выполнения. Для этого хочу сделать много одинаковых запросов и узнать среднюю скорость выполнения.

При помощи цикла повторяю запрос 100 раз.
Но после первого запроса к БД скорость резко увеличивается (первый 3ms, второй и последующие по 400μs).
Подумал, что это из за Cache. Отключил его в .env `(CACHE_DRIVER=none)` и в config cache прописал

```
'none' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],
```

Плюсом выполнил:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Скорость последующих запросов так же в 5 раз быстрее, чем первого.
В чём может быть причина?
Запросы делал при помощи моделей. Laravel 8

Comment: В MySQL есть кэш таблиц и кэш индексов. Первый запрос вызывает загрузку используемых таблиц/индексов в кэш, остальные работают уже с данными в кэше, и потому они быстрее. В старых версиях был ещё и кэш запросов, и если запрос из него не вымылся, что следующий вызов того же запроса получал результат из кэша, без выполнения запроса. Сейчас эта фича удалена.

Comment: Как то можно отключить эти кэш таблицы?

Comment: 1) Нет. Можно минимизировать размер кэшей - но это фатально скажется на производительности сервера. 2) А зачем?

Comment: Исключительно для тестов, что бы посмотреть и после включить

Comment: Это так не работает. Для тестов вполне достаточно тестировать именно горячий кэш - обычно в системе в режиме повседневной эксплуатации частоиспользуемые данные полностью или частично кэшированы. Холодный кэш Вы уже видите при первом запуске запроса. Можно, конечно, перед каждым тестируемым запросом вымывать кэш, выполняя промежуточный запрос, который требует считывания большого, много больше кэша, объёма данных - но дурь же. Я уж не говорю о рестарте сервиса перед каждым запросом.

Comment: ну да, такой способ точно не подойдёт. Спасибо за консультацию